# Selenium IDE data-driven storing special characters from csv file

Tags: selenium-ide, data-driven, csv-file

I'm using selenium IDE and `readCSV` command from a CSV file.

Within the file I have `Lägg till Värdorder` inside a cell. I'm using command storeCellValue and echo the value.

But it looks like this `L�gg till V�rdorder`

I need it to look like `Lägg till Värdorder`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758707/excel-read-special-characters, does it help? You may need to do some conversion.

Comment: CSV file does not provide any encoding. Excel guesses it, and gets it right (probably from your windows settings). IDE guesses and gets it wrong. Read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

The � that you see in your CSV file is due to you saving the file in one encoding and reading it in another. Always read/write the files in the correct encoding. 
You can decide on a particular encoding (UTF-8 should suffice mostly) and then use the same across all of your text editors, IDEs, Selenium IDE & spreadsheet programs.
You can achieve this by using 'Reopen with encoding' option that is available in most programs.

Solution: 
In Selenium IDE options, specify the selected encoding in 'Encoding of test files' field and this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To read CSV files you can use the Kantu Selenium IDE for Chrome which has a built-in [csvRead (= readCSV)](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/webextensions/selenium-ide/csvread) command with full unicode support. I use it with Chinese texts with no problems.